# C# overload question

Tags: c#, arguments, overloading, fallback

Is it possible to somehow implement the following scheme:

```
public interface ISomething
{
    void Go(ISpecific specific);

    void Go(Object o);
}
```

so that on every `Go(ISpecific)` call the first overload would be called and for the calls with any other possible objects the class would **fallback** to the `Go(Object)` implementation?

Comment: It will work.  What did you find when tried a simple example in the compiler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's how it will work by default - but using the *compile-time* types. If you have `Go(foo)` and the compile-time type of `foo` doesn't implement `ISpecific`, it will call the second method even if the object that `foo` refers to at execution time implements `ISpecific`. If you want this decision to be made dynamically at *execution time*, and if you're using C# 4, you could write:

```
dynamic value = GetValue();
something.Go(value);
```

... and at execution time, the correct overload will be selected.

Comment: Can you suggest an example of this form's usefulness? Funny, I was just reading one of your blog posts on variance and overloading this morning.

Comment: @Justin: I don't tend to do much in the way of dynamic typing, so I'm not sure... but it sounds like it's what the OP *might* be after.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. That is how the compiler works.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible to do that.  Note though that the decision on which overload to take will be done based on the compile time type of the reference.

```
ISpecific specificVar = null;
something.Go(specificVar);  // ISomething::Go(ISpecific)
object obj = specificVar;
something.Go(obj);  // ISomething::Go(object)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it definitely works, any object that is not ISpecific will call the object overload.

I wrote a console app to check.

it outputs

```
Object 
Object
Specific

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Object aSpecific = new Object();
        String nonSpecific = "nonSpecific";
        ISpecific specific = new Specific();

        ISomething something = new Something();

        something.Go(aSpecific);
        something.Go(nonSpecific);
        something.Go(specific);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

interface ISpecific
{
    void GoGo();
}

interface ISomething
{
    void Go(ISpecific specific)
    void Go(Object o)
}

Class Specific : ISpecific
{
    public Specific() { }

    public void GoGo()
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Specific");
    }
}

Class Something : ISomething
{
    public Something() { }

    public void Go(ISpecific specific)
    {
        specific.GoGo()
    }

    public void Go(Object o)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Object");
    }
}
```